# CRTP and the assignment operator

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I have some code that assigned to a CRTP class like this:

```
        IChunkWindow<WindowDerived, IChunk<ChunkDerived>> editWindow = chunkWindow.create(
                                                                chunkWindow.getOrigin().getX() + x / ChunkDimensions::MAX_X,
                                                                chunkWindow.getOrigin().getZ() + z / ChunkDimensions::MAX_Z,
                                                                chunkWindow);
```

and this is the CRTP class:

```
    template <class Derived, class T>
struct IChunkWindow : public IWindow<IChunkWindow<Derived,T>, T> {

    Point3D const& getOrigin() const {
        return static_cast<Derived const*>(this)->getOrigin();
    }

    void setOrigin(Point3D const& origin) {
        this->origin = origin;
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->setOrigin(origin);
    }
    T* getChunk(int cx, int cz) {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->getChunk(cx,cz);
    }
    void setChunk(int cx, int cz, T* ptr) {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->setChunk(cx,cz,ptr);
    }

    unsigned char getTerrainBlock(int x, int y, int z) const {
        return static_cast<Derived const*>(this)->getTerrainBlock(x,y,z);
    }
    void setTerrainBlock(int x, int y, int z, unsigned char value) {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->setTerrainBlock(x,y,z,value);
    }
    unsigned char getLightBlock(int x, int y, int z) const {
        return static_cast<Derived const*>(this)->getLightBlock(x,y,z);
    }
    void setLightBlock(int x, int y, int z, unsigned char value) {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->setLightBlock(x,y,z,value);
    }
    unsigned char getMetaBlock(int x, int y, int z) const {
        return static_cast<Derived const*>(this)->getMetaBlock(x,y,z);
    }
    void setMetaBlock(int x, int y, int z, unsigned char value) {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->setMetaBlock(x,y,z,value);
    }
    bool isChunkDirty(int cx, int cz) {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->isChunkDirty(cx,cz);
    }
    bool inBounds(int x, int y, int z) {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->inBounds(x,y,z);
    }
    bool inBounds(int a_cx, int a_cz) {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->inBounds(a_cx, a_cz);
    }
    void insert(int a_x, int a_y, int a_z, unsigned char blockType) {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->insert(a_x,a_y,a_z,blockType);
    }
    void remove(int a_x, int a_y, int a_z) {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->remove(a_x, a_y, a_z);
    }
    std::vector<BlockPosition> waterPhysics(int a_x, int a_y, int a_z, std::vector<BlockPosition> const& waterSources) {
        static_cast<Derived*>(this)->waterPhysics(a_x,a_y,a_z, waterSources);
    }

    IChunkWindow<Derived, T> create(int a_cx, int a_cz, IChunkWindow<Derived, T> & otherWindow) {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->create(a_cx, a_cz, otherWindow);
    }

};
```

I can make method calls on editWindow but the private data of the base class (not shown) is garbage so it appears that assignment is failing.  Do I need to override an assignment operator in the IChunkWindow class for this to work?

Comment: Unless `chunkWindow` is a reference, you're getting slicing because it's nothing but a `IChunkWindow`, it isn't really any more derived type and casting it to the derived type is invalid. Also returning an `IChunkWindow` by value from `create` causes slicing (and if that didn't slice, the assignment would). Further you don't show the class that inherits from `IChunkWindow`.

Comment: Do you want to define editWindow or */& editWindow ? If not */&, and you really mean an object, the compiler will create for you a copy constructor coping from what return chunkWindow.create() only the part of your class not the derived part.